# Should I store app settings in one column array? or create a multi-column table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building my first app right now, but I'm new to mysql databases.
I want to store users personalized settings in database, and here are two scenarios to make that happen:

**First one:**

```
COLUMNS: "uid" | "app_settings"
ROWS:      1   |  0,1,0,1,ffff00,#ff0000
```

Which is storing them as an array, and breaking them up by PHP explode.

**Second one:**

```
COLUMNS: "uid" | "show_menu" | "show_toolbar" | "show_email | "menu_color" | "toolbar_color"
ROWS:      1   |     0       |       1        |      1      |    #ffff00   | #ff0000
```

Which is storing each in a separate column.

Both ways work fine, but I want to know if it's a bad practice to use the first method.

Does the extra processes to break apart each value is overwhelming for the server resources in a large scale? (Using the PHP explode) or selecting multiple columns is somehow just like exploding them by php in terms of processing speed?

Comment: I'd use the second approach. There are likely to be times where you need to check only one setting's value, so fetching the whole thing is unnecessary and inefficient. It also permits indexing/filtering of users by setting - you could do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE show_email=1` to get a list of them, or update something for just those users.

Comment: Funny.  I'd go in a completely different direction.  I'd make a settings table, with three columns: `settings_id` (PRIMARY KEY), `setting_name`, and `setting_value`.   I'd store each setting in it's own row. Then when you want a setting, your query would simply be `SELECT setting_value FROM settings WHERE setting_name=?` (where ? would be the setting you wanted, such as `show_menu`).  This offers lots of flexibility to add various settings as you develop the app without having to modify code OR database structure.

Comment: @cale_b I'd go with that approach in *some* cases. It depends a bit on how frequently these settings are used. If they're fetched on every pageview, and every user has one, you're at least doubling queries to minimal benefit.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Thanks for the dialog.  I truly enjoy learning more.  You are suggesting that you could select settings in a single query (joined with the user info) in the other two methods, whereas my method would require it's own query, correct? I agree, and see that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what for do you intent to use this data.

Main purpose of using separate columns in database is to have ability to index such data.

If it is a matter of storage only you can use your storage format in one field, but it is much better to use well known format as json (json_encoding in PHP before storing in db, and json_decode after reading).
Also if you really want to save up space, then assuming, that things such as "show_menu" / "show_toolbar" are simply boolean flags, you can store them in one number as a bit fields. For example field named `show_rights` may have value of 6 which translates to binary 110, so [1: show_menu][1: show_toolbar][0: show_email].